# Mongoose: "Cast to embedded failed" error when updating by pushing an object to array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a document by adding an object to an array of objects. The array is a property of the document. The error message is simply:

```
CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value
```

+ the piece of object I'm trying to push. This is not very descriptive or helpful.

Here's my schema:

```
const timeoff = new Schema(
  {
    requestId: {
      type: Number,
      unique: true
    },
    // ... some other properties
    approvals: [{
      email: String,
      status: String,
      lastChangedStatus: Date,
      lastNotificationSent: Date
    }]
  },
  {
    usePushEach: true
  }
);
```

this is how I'm trying to add an `approval` object to the `approvals` array:

```
await this.findOneAndUpdate({ requestId }, { $push: { 'approvals': approval } });
```

and this is the `approval` object I'm providing:

```
  const approval = {
    email: 'test@example.com',
    status: 'pending',
    lastChangedStatus: 'requested',
    lastNotificationSent: this.moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') // which ends as '2019-10-28'
  };
```

This is the full error:

CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value "{\n' +
"  email: 'test@example.com',\n" +
"  status: 'pending',\n" +
"  lastChangedStatus: 'requested',\n" +
"  lastNotificationSent: '2019-10-28'\n" +
'}" at path "approvals"

So, I'm not really sure how to approach this. The types of data in the properties correctly matches the types of properties of the schema. What else could the problem be?

mongoose: `^5.7.4`

mongodb: `4.2.0`

Comment: Try defining as new schema. So: `approvals: [new Schema({email: String,
      status: String,
      lastChangedStatus: Date,
      lastNotificationSent: Date})]`

Answer (score 0):

In the schema `lastChangedStatus: Date` it is a `Date` property. But, in your `approval` object it is a `String`. I believe this is where it gets stuck.